# how to implement an email to post system in php

Tags: php, email, blogs

I would like to know how to setup a system in php that I could send emails to and the email content would poblish on my blog as a new post and the email subject  would be the new post title.

Am not using word press or any of those blogging platforms am running my own blogging script and a php 5.x version.

I don't even know how to get started on this kind of programming challenge please any one with any ideas is welcomed.

Joe

Comment: if you are programming challenged then you should use a blogging platform to start off and not challenge yourself to this. you would obviously need a database that would store all of the email posts that people submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a script that is able to read from your email account. Php has the [IMAP library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.imap.php) that enables you to read email messages. [Check this link](http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/reading-emails-with-php/) to see how you could use the library.

You would need to schedule the script to be run at a periodic interval of time (eg. every 5 minutes). In Linux you would setup a cron job to do it.
So, I mean the script should be invoked periodically. If it finds a new message, it would then update your blog by taking the body of the email.

Comment: Or if your email storage is not on an IMAP account, maybe look at Procmail.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set up a database that has all the tables and rows necessary to hold all the vital information about the post that people will send via email. then using MYSQL in your PHP file you need to connect to the database (host, username, and password) and then create your own query to enter the desired data to the database.